# Converting ASCII value to String

Tags: serial, arduino-mega

I have this code.

```
String incoming;   // for incoming serial data

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);  // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
}

void loop() {

    // send data only when you receive data:
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
            // read the incoming byte:
            incoming = Serial.read();
            String mysrr = String(incoming);
            // say what you got:
            Serial.print("I received: ");
            Serial.println(mysrr);
    }
}
```

A few of you will recognise this as an Arduino example.

However, when I run it ( I sent it the message "hi"), I get this in the serial:

```
I received: 104
I received: 105
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serial.read() returns an int not a String. https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read

Use an int for incoming (as the example). Or even better use a char and skip all the strings.

Cheers!